# ServiceController.start() and ServiceController.stop() are throwing exceptions?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-services

The following code is throwing Exception. I don't get what mistake I am making in the code. Can somebody help me figure out please. I think it is of some security rights issue. If so, how can I give the security rights to any user or application to access this windows service programmatically?

```
Dim sc As New ServiceController        
sc.ServiceName = "DataLoad"   
If sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then     
    sc.Start()    
Else  
    sc.Stop()  
End If
```

**Exception**:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open DataLoad service on computer '.'. --->
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess) at
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args) at
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start() at
WEBSITE.DataLoad.Submit1_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WEBSITE\a\DataLoad.aspx.vb:line 46
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subinacl` tool for that

```
SUBINACL /SERVICE \\MachineName\ServiceName /GRANT=[DomainName\]UserName[=Access]
```

To be specfic for your case:

```
subinacl /service DataLoad /GRANT=YOURDOMAIN\[User in appdomain for WEBSITE]=TO
```

Where `TO` means
   T : Start Service
   O : Stop Service

all options for [Access] are:

F : Full Control
   R : Generic Read
   W : Generic Write
   X : Generic eXecute
   L : Read controL
   Q : Query Service Configuration
   S : Query Service Status
   E : Enumerate Dependent Services
   C : Service Change Configuration
   T : Start Service
   O : Stop Service
   P : Pause/Continue Service
   I : Interrogate Service
   U : Service User-Defined Control Commands

See [Method 3 in this kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288129)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I would appreciate  if you can explain on how to do it the other way (group policy or some other way) with out using the third party code.
Thank you!

Comment: subinacl is part of the windows resource kit. I do not consider that as "third party code". http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en

Comment: you can try setting the permission with the Local Security Policy tool (under Control Panel > Administrative tools) and set Local Policies > User Right Assingments > Log on as a server - Now add the account form the web apppool to that list.

Comment: In my case, I kept getting this error:  LookupAccountName : MySvc:pdsclocalsystem 1337 The security ID structure is invalid.

Current object MySvc will not be processed

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem by providing the machine name of the machine which is currently executing the service in the ServiceController overloaded constructor that takes 2(two) arguments i.e. 
public ServiceController(/*my service's name string*/, System.Environment.MachineName/*this machine which is executing the service*/)

The version of .Net this solution was tested on was 4.5, hope this helps anyone still looking for a solution.

Here is what you need to do in code:

```
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController("myServiceName", System.Environment.MachineName);
```

Comment: This could still give you problems by starting the service already started if the status haven't changed on time.

Answer (score 1):

`GetServiceHandle` requires some access rights. If it works when you run it as an Admin user, but not as a normal user, then maybe this article can help.

It clearly shows you how to manually give a Windows User rights to start and stop services (or set other permissions):

http://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/how-to-allow-non-admins-to-start-and-stop-system-services/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I determined that I needed to adjust the security on my service to allow it be be restarted by a separate "watchdog" service if my service fails.

First, open mmc.exe, then add the "Security Configuration and Analysis" and Security Templates" snap-ins.

[image]

Then create a new blank security template from the "Security Templates" item, give it a name, and hit OK to save it on your local disk drive somewhere convenient.

Then open "Security Configuration and Analysis" and choose "Open Database...", give it a name, and save it in the same directory as the previous step.  When an "Import Template" window appears, open the *.inf file in the same directory.

Next, right-click "Security Configuration and Analysis" and choose "Analyze Computer..."  The following will appear:

[image]

Double-click on "System Services", locate and double-click on your service, then click the checkbox "Define this policy in the database" and click on the "Edit Security" button.

This is where it becomes different than what is described in the link @JOG posted since I am using Windows 8.1--I enabled "start, stop and pause" for "INTERACTIVE" and "SERVICE"

[image]

FYI, I performed the above by following this guide as @JOG suggested: https://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/how-to-allow-non-admins-to-start-and-stop-system-services/

Comment: The extra details in the hyperlink are what finally helped me get across the finish line. Thanks for this!!

Answer (score -1):

If you are already having the Service user as LocalSystem(the high privilage user) the problem is not security. Also I had that problem before and its the status vrs starting it again or stopping it when already commande to stop().

You see the service status its not changed on demand, so even if you coded

```
//this will start the process but the 
//sc status will take some time to change
//when that happens and you try to start 
//the already started service it will give you 
//your error
servicec.start();
```

Soo you need to do this: 
[msdn ServiceController.waitforstatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w52kaf2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 Dim sc As New ServiceController
     sc.ServiceName = "DataLoad"   
If sc.Status = ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped     Then     
    sc.Start()    
 // this makes it wait for the status to change
  // and no it wont slow down anything at all. 
sc.waitforstatus(ServiceControllerStatus.started)
Else  
    sc.Stop()
sc.waitforstatus(ServiceControllerStatus.stopped)
End If
```

This will solve your problem like it did mine.