# Why does an imppersonated identity has less rights than the original identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, security

I have a ASP.NET MVC2 Service, which is hosted by a cassini/http.sys based web server. The service process runs as local administrator.

No I want to read the status of a service using:

```
using (var sc = new ServiceController(_ServiceName))
{
    return sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
}
```

This works great then impersonation is off. But I want to use windows authentication and impersonation. So when I add

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

to the web.config. The call to sc.Status fails with an InvalidOperationException. The inner exception is Win32Exception / ACCESS_DENIED.

```
"System.InvalidOperationException" caught. 
Message=Cannot open service 'abcd' on computer '.' .
Source=System.ServiceProcess
StackTrace:
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
   Message=Access denied
   ErrorCode=-2147467259
   NativeErrorCode=5
   InnerException:
```

The impersonated identity is the same as the process identity. So why does the impersonated identity have less access rights than the process identity? And how can this be avoided?

System: Windows 7, UAC enabled

Comment: So you're accessing the Service from the same machine using the same local administrator account, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's only one machine, and there's only one user account. (The logged on account, service process account and impersonated account are all the same)

Comment: I just found this: "Notice that remote users authenticated over the network but not interactively logged on can connect to the SCM but not perform operations that require other access rights. To perform these operations, the user must be logged on interactively or the service must use one of the service accounts." [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So, as the impersonated identity is remote identity, it does not have the required access rights.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your server is not [trusted for delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738491(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: This is a stand alone computer, no domain/server

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I solved the above problem--please see my post here:  [ServiceController.start() and ServiceController.stop() are throwing exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084493/servicecontroller-start-and-servicecontroller-stop-are-throwing-exceptions/28307342#28307342) and the original article here: https://thommck.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/how-to-allow-non-admins-to-start-and-stop-system-services/