# How to start or stop IIS and also a Windows Service in remote machine using C#

Tags: c#

Getting Exception with this code... eventhough I've administrator privileges in the remote machine

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("W3SVC", "10.201.58.114");
            sc.Start();
            sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running);            
            sc.Stop();
            sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
        }
    }
```

**Exception**:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceProcess.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '10.201.58.114'. This operation might require other privileges.

Comment: Is the target system free of security software? You'll find that some security software can have this effect.

Comment: would it help to run app "As Administrator" ? also assuming that you have rights to IP provided ...

Comment: With Command Prompt using as Administrator: `C:\>iisreset.exe <ip address of remote computer>`, Getting error as: `Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this
command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of
the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group.` Please note that I've administrator rights in the remote machine but still error is getting.

Answer (score 1):

Are the machines in the same domain? If not `Administrator` on machine1 is not equivalent `Administrator` on machine2, so that could be your problem.

One possibility is that you need to grant access for this user - on the remote machine - to stop and start the service like so:

```
SUBINACL /SERVICE \\<MACHINE>\W3SVC /GRANT=<MACHINE>\<USER>=TO
```

There's an example of this in the comments of the second code block below (as I needed this even with the in-code identity impersonation).

If this doesn't solve the problem, you could try impersonating the remote user. I managed to get this working using the following code.

First, create a new class WrapperImpersonationContext.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.ComponentModel;

//Version from http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/windowsimpersonationcontext-made-easy/

public class WrapperImpersonationContext
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

    private string m_Domain;
    private string m_Password;
    private string m_Username;
    private IntPtr m_Token;

    private WindowsImpersonationContext m_Context = null;


    protected bool IsInContext
    {
        get { return m_Context != null; }
    }

    public WrapperImpersonationContext(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        m_Domain = domain;
        m_Username = username;
        m_Password = password;
    }

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Enter()
    {
        if (this.IsInContext) return;
        m_Token = new IntPtr(0);
        try
        {
            m_Token = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool logonSuccessfull = LogonUser(
                m_Username,
                m_Domain,
                m_Password,
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                ref m_Token);
            if (logonSuccessfull == false)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }
            WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(m_Token);
            m_Context = identity.Impersonate();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Catch exceptions here
        }
    }


    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public void Leave()
    {
        if (this.IsInContext == false) return;
        m_Context.Undo();

        if (m_Token != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(m_Token);
        m_Context = null;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to run the following. Note that you'll need to change the machine-name, user-name and password to match your setup. Also pay attention to the comments as there's important security settings information that I discovered along the way:

```
//Code for Program.cs demonstrating the identity impersonation for a ServiceController.

using System;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace RemoteConnectionTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            try {

                //Based on the code from http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/windowsimpersonationcontext-made-easy/

                Console.WriteLine("Current user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                //Also worked with the IP address of GARNET (which was the machine name).
                WrapperImpersonationContext context = new WrapperImpersonationContext("GARNET", "TestAdmin1", "password123");
                context.Enter();
                // Execute code under other uses context
                Console.WriteLine("Current user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                // Code to execute.

                //Try running the following command on the remote server first to ensure
                //the user has the appropriate access (obviously substitute the
                //username and machine name).
                // runas /user:TestAdmin "sc \\GARNET stop W3SVC"

                //Also, make sure the user on the remote server has access for
                //services granted as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5084563/201648
                //Otherwise you may see an error along the lines of:
                //Cannot open W3SVC service on computer '<SERVER>'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
                //For my configuration I had to run the command:
                // SUBINACL /SERVICE \\GARNET\W3SVC /GRANT=GARNET\TestAdmin=TO
                //It's entirely possible that running this command will allow your existing code to work without using impersonation.

                //You may need to install SUBINACL https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=23510
                //By default SUBINACL will install to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools
                //so CD to that directory and then run the SUBINACL command above.

                //Also worked with the IP address of GARNET (which was the machine name).
                var sc = new ServiceController("W3SVC", "GARNET");
                sc.Start();

                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);            
                sc.Stop();
                sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);

                //END - code to execute.
                context.Leave();
                Console.WriteLine("Your code ran successfully. Current user: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception occured - details as follows: {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("The full stack trace is: {0}", ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

}
```

Ensure that the remote machine can be assessed using the provided credentials before you try to do this in code e.g. by connecting as this user through remote desktop.

Comment: **Error**: `The type or namespace name 'RemoteAccessHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Did you look at the code in the tutorial http://dotnet-assembly.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/c-accessing-remote-file-by-using.html

Comment: So just to clarify 1) determine the computer/domain name of the remote machine 2) attempt to connect to the remote machine from the machine where your code will be running from using that computer/domain name and the username and password outside of the code, e.g. using remote desktop 3) if you're successful, attempt the C# impersonation based on the code in that tutorial. Also, did you determine if you're on a domain or not? If both the machines are on the same domain it might be some other issue.

Comment: Both the machines are at same domain. I'm able to ping the remote machine but not able to connect the remote machine  Still I'm getting same Exception as `System.InvalidOperationException`

Comment: Ignore the code for now. You MUST be able to connect to the remote machine for the desired user outside the code, or this code will never work. When I've done this in the past I've setup remote desktop for the user to test whether there was some connectivity issue before trying to do this with code https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc758036(v=ws.10).aspx. Other than that, can you tell me where you're getting that error. I'm trying to reproduce this locally now.

Comment: Getting that exception at `sc.Start();` Please provide the prerequisites to be checked or make ready for the same.

Comment: I managed to get a new version working in my test environment using slightly different code but the same concept. You'll noticed that there's some comments regarding security in there based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5084563/201648. My solution didn't work until I'd run the ACL commands, so this could explain the exception you were encountering. You might also like to try that command before you try the impersonation code to see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101373/discussion-between-sukumar-and-aaron-newton).

Comment: No change. Still the exception remains is same.

Comment: I've invited you to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not added to the localgroup administrators

Check this with

> net localgroup Administrators

on the remote machine

if the user is not in the list, run

> net localgroup Administrators /add user

Comment: My name is already listed in Localgroup of Administrators. But still getting the same exception.