# How can i start and stop a service remotely

Tags: c#

this is my first time posting here and my second time coding. So in order to learn how all this works, i try to look up code snippets and copy/paste them until my application seems to run. I have written some batch and ps scripts before but to be honest, i'm more into system administration and hardware....until now!

My project is a simple GUI tool to start and stop the TeamViewer service on a certain server. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and it seemed to work until i started the application on my colleagues computers to show them how to use it.

I get the error: System.InvalidOperationException: Der Dienst TeamViewer kann nicht auf dem Computer MYSERVERNAME geöffnet werden. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Zugriff verweigert, which obviously has to do with user privileges. So i googled for quite a while about Impersonation and WMI service credentials but now i'm stuck and have to ask you guys for your help.

So here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String svcName = "TeamViewer";
        String machineName = "MYSERVERNAME";
        var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(svcName, machineName);
        sc.Start();
        sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
    }

    private void AUS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String svcName = "TeamViewer";
        String machineName = "MYSERVERNAME";
        var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(svcName, machineName);
        sc.Stop();
        sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
    }
}
```

I'd be very happy if anybody could help me out!

p.s.: My Powershell Scripts worked like a charm but i want to make it look more sophisticated :)

Edit1: The server where i try to stop/start the service is not a member of the domain but every member of the domain should be able to stop/start the service.

Comment: Do you authenticate to the remote machine? It would be very nasty if everyone with an IP address was allowed to start & stop services on a remote machine

Comment: If you have a powershell script that works you could always just launch the script and have it do the work.

Comment: did you try running your app with elevated privileges?

Comment: and please have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919343/how-to-start-or-stop-iis-and-also-a-windows-service-in-remote-machine-using-c-sh?rq=1

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Actually, i'm looking for a way to do that... is there a possibility to put the authentication into the code?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I had a look at this too, but that seemed to be quite difficult to code, isn't it?

Comment: @swe Yes i tried that but still get the error. I also had a look at quite a few different threads but didn't find a proper solution for my problem.

Comment: so did you make sure, your userrights on the remote computer is corrent and you started locally with elevated privileges?

Comment: @swe Well, maybe i have a problem understanding the difference. So i have my PC where i run the IDE and where i am logged on to as domain\user. I am a Domain Administrator in this domain. The remote machine name which has the TeamViewer service installed -lets call it - Server is a non-domain server which has a local administrator Server\administrator. Isn't there any way to use the code that i have but somehow tell it to authentiate to the Server ?

Comment: i don't know, if you need elevated privileges locally, i would give it a try... how do do the signon in powershell? not at all? in the link i postet above, there is an example, how you can change the usercontext at runtime, you should try to adapt that. sry, i do not have time to give a complete example.

Answer (score 7):

i found a post, that helped me completing my code. It can be found [here](http://learn-vsdotnet.blogspot.de/2013/03/start-or-stop-services-on-remote-machine.html).

Edit1:
Here's how the code looks like now:

```
private void EIN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      try
            {

                #region Code to start the service

                string serviceName = "TeamViewer";
                string IP="actual-IP-address";
                string username ="actual-username";
                string password ="actual-password";

                ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
                //connectoptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                connectoptions.Username = username;
                connectoptions.Password = password;

                //IP Address of the remote machine

                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + IP + @"\root\cimv2");
                scope.Options = connectoptions;

                //WMI query to be executed on the remote machine
                SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service where name = '" + serviceName + "'");

                using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
                            ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
                {
                    ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
                    foreach (ManagementObject service in collection)
                    {
                        if (service["Started"].Equals(false))
                        {
                            //Start the service
                            service.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
                            //here i added a picture box which shows a green button when the service is started
                            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources._120px_Green_Light_I_svg;
                      }

                    }
                }

       #endregion

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {

            }
    }
```

Comment: You should include the essentials of this post in your answer - who guarantees the existance of the the very link in the future? Additionally, you should address any concerns with your solution in an additional **question** rather than including it in your answer. Finally, I have no clue who you are talking to with *Nevertheless you ...*

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair Thanks for the instructions. I am talking to the people commenting on my question because i think it's very nice of them trying to help me with my problem.

Comment: I had to hard code the username and password, which i think is bad practice? What do you think?